# Sending messages from java servlet to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I need help. I have single html-file running on my webserver. Via Javascript I'm sending data to my Java-Servlet on the same server via xhttp-request. 
On Java's servlet side I can send a message back to the xhttp-request via a PrintWriter like below:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
          PrintWriter theMessenger = response.getWriter();
          theMessenger.print("Response data");
    }
```

That all works fine. But now I need to send a message to the requesting html-file **without** the use of the servlet-response. 
Are there any possibilities for sending data (strings as usual) to the html-file gathering those messages via onmessage-handler for example?

I tried this, but the messange never reaches it target:

```
String targetURL = CSConfig.GetRootURL() + "/myRequestingPage.html";
URL objUrl = new URL(targetURL);
HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection) objUrl.openConnection();
urlCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlCon.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream dataWriter = new DataOutputStream(urlCon.getOutputStream());
dataWriter.writeBytes(messageContent);
dataWriter.flush();
dataWriter.close();
```

Comment: You are looking for websockets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: yeah that may work with some changes in my environment... thanks dude.

Comment: A thing to keep in mind: html (or the javascript referenced inside it) does not run on a server. It is served from a server and 'runs' in the browser - on the client. An important distinction to really hammer into your brain.